# Get a pointer to a subordinate YAML::Node

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

I am writing a config file library, and I'd like to have a pointer to a sub-node to pass to functions expecting `YAML::Node*`, for example for building up a YAML document.

I can create a new Node and get a pointer easily enough:

```
YAML::Node* foo = new YAML::Node(); // Null node
```

and I can add a new sub node easily enough:

```
(*foo)["bar"] = baz;
```

However, I don't know how to get a pointer to `(*foo)["bar"]`. If I try

```
&((*foo)["bar"]);
```

I get `error: taking address of temporary`, which is true, because the `[]` operator returns a YAML::Node. Is there a way to get a pointer to `(*foo)["bar"]` so that I can pass it to something like

```
void f(YAML::Node* const blah) 
{
    (*blah)["banana"] = 1;
}
```

which is useful, because then I can build up a tree with recursive calls to `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a `YAML::Node`, not a pointer. `YAML::Node` is already a reference type, so you can pass it like a pointer.